# GeoTools WFS Query sortBy not working for GeoServer WFS

Tags: geotools

I am using GeoTools to query a GeoServer WFS using the following code:

```
    Map connectionParameters = new HashMap();
    connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL", String.format("%s&request=GetCapabilities", wfsUrl));
    connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:TIMEOUT", connectionTimeout*1000);
    DataStore data = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(connectionParameters);
    SimpleFeatureType schema = data.getSchema("airports");
    FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> source = data.getFeatureSource( typeName );
    String geomName = schema.getGeometryDescriptor().getLocalName();
    Envelope bbox = new Envelope( -100.0, -70, 25, 40 );

    FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2(GeoTools.getDefaultHints());
    Object polygon = JTS.toGeometry(bbox);
    Intersects filter = ff.intersects( ff.property( geomName ), ff.literal( polygon ) );

    Query query = new DefaultQuery( typeName, filter, new String[]{ geomName } );
    query.setSortBy(new SortBy[]{ff.sort("country", SortOrder.ASCENDING)});
    FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> features = source.getFeatures( query );
```

The query returns features, but sorting never works.  A toString() on the query returns something like:

> feature type: airports    filter: [[ geom intersects POLYGON
>   ((-117.8395870053188 31.58066038426718, -115.5957867039628
>   31.58066038426718, -115.5957867039628 33.27328332002949, -117.8395870053188 33.27328332002949, -117.8395870053188 31.58066038426718)) ]]    [properties:  ALL ]    [sort by: country ASCENDING]

which indicates that sorting is part of the query.

The following direct WFS query works:

```
http://thing:8080/geoserver/ix/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=airports&srsName=epsg:4326&bbox=-117.8395870053188,31.58066038426718,-115.5957867039628,33.27328332002949&sortBy=country
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what happens if you include country in the Query attribute list? e.g. Query query = new DefaultQuery( typeName, filter, new String[]{ geomName, "country" } );

Comment: I get an exception if I don't specify the attribute I'm sorting on. See https://gitlab.com/snippets/3277

Comment: Thanks for the answer...  This change just reduced the number of properties returned, but still not sorted by country.  Here is the output:{
{
"rows": [
{
"geom": "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coords\":[-116.602,31.795]}",
"country": "Mexico"
},
{
"geom": "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coords\":[-116.97,32.541]}",
"country": "Mexico"
},
{
"geom": "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coords\":[-117.215,32.699]}",
"country": "United States"
},
{
"geom": "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coords\":[-116.624,31.855]}",
"country": "Mexico"
},
{
"geom": "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coords\":[-116.915,33.039]}",
"country": "United States"
}
]
}

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. If you use WFS version 1.0.0 sortBy does not work. Using version 1.1.0 works.

Comment: can you share your code for a MWE? - I suspect that is a bug.